# Determining minimum value based on Hessian Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

In my book, for $2\times2$ hessian matrix, it says that if determinant of hessian matrix is $0$, then whether function reaches min or max at critical point $(x,y)$ is inconclusive.

However, if we know that one of the eigenvalues is positive, then can we say that $(x,y)$ is a minimum point? (not unique though)

Conversely, if we know that one of the eigenvalues is negative, then can we say that $(x,y)$ is a maximum point?

Comment: Nope, consider something like $x^2 - y^4$. At the origin, the eigenvalue corr. to $x$ direction is positive, to $y$ direction is $0$. Instead of a minimum, the origin is a saddle point.

Answer (score 1):

If the $2 \times 2$ Hessian $H(x,y)$ has one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue, then $(x,y)$ is a saddle point (so neither a local minimum nor a local maximum).

This is mentioned in this Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#The_test

Answer (score 0):

What you can say in this cases is the following:

A.  If one is zero and one is negative, then it is NOT a minimum, but can be either saddle or maximum.

Example: $x^3-y^2$ at the origin. Hessian has $0$ and $-2$. Saddle point.

Example: $-x^4-y^2$ at the origin. Same eigenvalues, a maximum.

B.  If one is zero and one is positive, then it is NOT a maximum, but can be either saddle or minimum.

Example: multiply examples in A. by $-1$.

Bottom line: the test is conclusive only when both eigenvsalues are nonzero (determinant is nonzero).